# MySQL "unknown"

Tags: mysql

I just discovered [you can write](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is) something like

```
SELECT NULL IS UNKNOWN
```

Which returns `1`.

Are there any other places you can use `UNKNOWN`? It doesn't appear to be a keyword (can't do `SELECT UNKNOWN`). `NULL IS NULL` is also true, so what purpose does `UNKNOWN` have?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`UNKNOWN` is just an alias for `BOOLEAN` `NULL`... the same way that `TRUE` is just an alias for `1` and `FALSE` is just an alias for `0`, since [in MySql `BOOLEAN` itself is just an alias for `TINYINT(1)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

Why is it even there? Because it's part of the SQL-92 standard:

```
<truth value> ::=
                TRUE
              | FALSE
              | UNKNOWN
```

Why can you `SELECT NULL`, `SELECT TRUE`, `SELECT FALSE`, but not `SELECT UNKNOWN`?  Probably just a bug, [since `UNKNOWN` itself wasn't supported until newer versions of MySql](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24531).

Comment: +1 with a minor notice: considering `TRUE` as an alias for `1` is a bit misleading since `2 IS TRUE` (and any other non-zero integer), but you can't actually do `SELECT 2 IS 1`

Answer (score 4):

Seems to me, in MySQL, `UNKNOWN` is an alias for `NULL`, used in a Boolean sense.

I could find this reference:

> In SQL, all logical operators evaluate to TRUE, FALSE, or NULL (UNKNOWN).

[MySQL docs - 12.3.3. Logical Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html)

Some more information on general SQL NULL and UNKNOWN:

> When restricted by a NOT NULL constraint, the SQL BOOLEAN works like
>   the Boolean type from other languages. Unrestricted however, the
>   BOOLEAN datatype, despite its name, can hold the truth values TRUE,
>   FALSE, and UNKNOWN, all of which are defined as boolean literals
>   according to the standard. The standard also asserts that NULL and
>   UNKNOWN "may be used interchangeably to mean exactly the same thing".

[NULL on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Data_typing_of_Null_and_Unknown)

Comment: It's not an alias though. As I pointed out, you can do `SELECT NULL` but not `SELECT UNKNOWN`. You mean it's essentially an alias when used with the `IS` operator?

Comment: @Mark It basically seems to be the missing third Boolean value :). So far it seems to only work with `IS` and `IS NOT`.

Answer (score 1):

It's only use is to describe an boolean value that has no known value. Just like first example says, it's boolean equivalent of `NULL`.

Comment: Because in MySQL `NULL IS UNKNOWN` and of course you can `SELECT 'asdf' IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

When comparisons involve NULLs, in such cases, `unknown` comes into picture.

For example, consider the query:

```
select* from tbl
where x>5
```

Here, assume some tuples may contain null values for `x` column.
Now, while evaluating each tuple:

1. if x is non-null and x>5, then the expression `x>5` will evaluate to true
2. if x is non-null and x<=5, then the expression `x>5` will evaluate to false
3. But if x is null, then what will the expression `x>5` evaluate to?  (Ans-unknown)

For case-3, saying any of true or false is wrong. So, to handle case-3, another logical value is present in sql which is `unknown`.

(Thus, there are 3 logical values in sql: true, false, unknown)

Now, the rule is:

> If the where clause predicate evaluates to either false or unknown for a tuple, then that tuple is not added to the result.

Hence, for the above example, only case-1 tuples will get added to the result.

In this way, SQL plays with unknown internally.

Also, we have some results when the where clause predicates involve multiple logical expressions:

- Result of expression `true and unknown` is `unknown`
- Result of expression `false and unknown` is `false`
- Result of expression `unknown and unknown` is `unknown`
- Result of expression `true or unknown` is `true`
- Result of expression `false or unknown` is `unknown`
- Result of expression `unknown or unknown` is `unknown`
- Result of expression `not unknown` is `unknown`